# not able to add a column into dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The below is the result of `df.head()` where df is the dataframe

```
    Runs    Mins    BF  4s  6s  SR  Pos Dismissal   Inns    Opposition  Ground  Start Date
0   12  33  22  1   0   54.54   2   lbw 1   v Sri Lanka Dambulla    2008-08-18
1   37  82  67  6   0   55.22   2   caught  2   v Sri Lanka Dambulla    2008-08-20
2   25  40  38  4   0   65.78   1   run out 1   v Sri Lanka Colombo (RPS)   2008-08-24
3   54  87  66  7   0   81.81   1   bowled  1   v Sri Lanka Colombo (RPS)   2008-08-27
4   31  45  46  3   1   67.39   1   lbw 2   v Sri Lanka Colombo (RPS)   2008-08-29
```

I am trying to add a new column year, by extracting it from 'Start Date' and the dtype of Start Date is `datetime64[ns]`

I tried both of the below:

`df["year"] =  pd.DatetimeIndex(df["Start Date"]).year`

and

`df["year"] = df["Start Date"].dt.year`

but not able to add a column and it throws error

```
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last) ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in
> get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    2645             try:
> -> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)    2647             except KeyError:
> 
> pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
> 
> pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
> 
> pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
> 
> pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
> 
> KeyError: 'Year'
> 
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> 
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last) ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py
> in set(self, item, value)    1070         try:
> -> 1071             loc = self.items.get_loc(item)    1072         except KeyError:
> 
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in
> get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    2647             except
> KeyError:
> -> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))    2649        
> indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
> 
> pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
> 
> pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
> 
> pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
> 
> pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
> 
> KeyError: 'Year'
> 
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> 
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-53-212e4faa5daa> in <module>
>       1 #Your code here
> ----> 2 df["Year"] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df["Start Date"]).year
> 
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in
> __setitem__(self, key, value)    2936         else:    2937             # set column
> -> 2938             self._set_item(key, value)    2939     2940     def _setitem_slice(self, key, value):
> 
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _set_item(self,
> key, value)    2999         self._ensure_valid_index(value)    3000   
> value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
> -> 3001         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)    3002     3003         # check if we are modifying a copy
> 
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in
> _set_item(self, key, value)    3622     3623     def _set_item(self, key, value) -> None:
> -> 3624         self._data.set(key, value)    3625         self._clear_item_cache()    3626 
> 
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in
> set(self, item, value)    1072         except KeyError:    1073       
> # This item wasn't present, just insert at end
> -> 1074             self.insert(len(self.items), item, value)    1075             return    1076 
> 
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in
> insert(self, loc, item, value, allow_duplicates)    1192         if
> loc == self._blklocs.shape[0]:    1193             # np.append is a
> lot faster, let's use it if we can.
> -> 1194             self._blklocs = np.append(self._blklocs, 0)    1195             self._blknos = np.append(self._blknos,
> len(self.blocks))    1196         else:
> 
> <__array_function__ internals> in append(*args, **kwargs)
> 
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in
> append(arr, values, axis)    4689         if arr.ndim != 1:    4690   
> arr = arr.ravel()
> -> 4691         values = ravel(values)    4692         axis = arr.ndim-1    4693     return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
> 
> <__array_function__ internals> in ravel(*args, **kwargs)
> 
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in ravel(a,
> order)    1792     1793     """
> -> 1794     if isinstance(a, np.matrix):    1795         return asarray(a).ravel(order=order)    1796     else:
> 
> AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'matrix'
```

But when i try `df2 =  df["Start Date"].dt.year`, there is no error and
values of year is present in df2

`Name: Start Date, Length: 132, dtype: int64`

Comment: If you are sure *dtype of Start Date datetime64[ns]*, you don't need `pd.DatetimeIndex` in `pd.DatetimeIndex(df["Start Date"])`.

Comment: I don't understand how you can't set a new column to a `pd.Series`, and yet you are able to create the Series `df2`. What return value do you get from `df["Start Date"].dt.year`?

Comment: now how do i add a column year extracting from 'Start Date' column?
when i read the csv , default dtype was Object , hence i first converted into datetime , by df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

df['year']= df['Start Date'].apply(lambda x: (x[-2:]))

finally the above worked. Thanks everyone , however at start when the datatype was Object , executing above line without converting the column dtype to datetime

another solution is to convert it into datetime

```
df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date']).dt.year
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
df['year']= = df['Start Date'].apply(lambda dt: dt.year)
```